# You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === "production"

Tags: angular, webpack, angular9

I am getting the error like this

```
You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === "production". This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux. You can use loose-envify (https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify) for browserify or setting mode to production in webpack (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/) to ensure you have the correct code for your production build.
```

I recently upgraded my project to angular 9 from angular 6.

I also tried
1)"webpack:server": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
2)"webpack:server": "webpack -p --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
3)new webpack.DefinePlugin({
'process.env': {
'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
}
})
4)new webpack.DefinePlugin({
'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
})

```
5)new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/,
      minimize: true
    })
```

Comment: Is it for angular universal?

Answer (score 0):

"webpack:server": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"

this worked in my project.
run webpack after editing your package.json